# what does mean "a temporal linkage"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Drug trafficking creates ***a temporal linkage*** between the fates of communities in the developed and developing worlds, even if the numbers of persons involved is quite small.

Comment: Temporal relates to time, so a temporal linkage means that two things are related by time- for example they happen one after another. I think that more of the original text is required to know what this means in this context.

Comment: @JavaLatte - It is from this, but it still makes no sense to me: http://tinyurl.com/z9yfam2 Look under "Complex Crises."

Comment: do you men "simultaneously" ?

Comment: @yorgun: the word "temporal" adds no information and could have been omitted by the author.

Answer (score 1):

This language is a bit ostentatious, but the simple meaning of "temporal linkage" means that the two communities are linked together in time. 
An example might be that drugs imported from the "developing world" at a certain time from one community (providing the societal impact of potential profit as well as potential risk of jail time, etc.) will also have a societal impact on the community in the "developed" world where the drugs are bought and used. This might be in the number of homicides in that period related to selling drugs, kids not doing well in school, increase of crime to pay for the drugs, etc. The use of "temporal linkage" could be also said as "in the same timeframe" or "the same period of time."